# Issue with the format of printing in Prolog

Tags: prolog, format

I have the following code:

```
everything:-give_birth(X), give_eggs(Y),
    format('Animal Name: \t~w,  \tGives Birth', X), nl,  
    format('Animal Name: \t~w,  \tGives egg', Y), nl,fail.
```

and this is the output:

```
Animal Name:    cheetah,    Gives Birth
Animal Name:    ostrich,    Gives egg
Animal Name:    cheetah,    Gives Birth
Animal Name:    penguin,    Gives egg
Animal Name:    cheetah,    Gives Birth
Animal Name:    albatross,  Gives egg
Animal Name:    tiger,  Gives Birth
Animal Name:    ostrich,    Gives egg
Animal Name:    tiger,  Gives Birth
Animal Name:    penguin,    Gives egg
Animal Name:    tiger,  Gives Birth
Animal Name:    albatross,  Gives egg
Animal Name:    giraffe,    Gives Birth
Animal Name:    ostrich,    Gives egg
Animal Name:    giraffe,    Gives Birth
Animal Name:    penguin,    Gives egg
Animal Name:    giraffe,    Gives Birth
Animal Name:    albatross,  Gives egg
Animal Name:    zebra,  Gives Birth
Animal Name:    ostrich,    Gives egg
Animal Name:    zebra,  Gives Birth
Animal Name:    penguin,    Gives egg
Animal Name:    zebra,  Gives Birth
Animal Name:    albatross,  Gives egg
```

first problem is:
    I want the third column to be aligned.

Second problem: the output is not what I want it, I want it first to print all the animals that gives birth which are only 4(the rest are repeated in this output I don't know why). and then the rest of the animals that gives egg.

Comment: Of interest: [format/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=format/2) and [Formatted Write](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the third column to be aligned.

I don't normally use [format/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=format/2) with Prolog because the concept of the tabs just drives me nuts. Also I use Prolog mainly for solving AI problems and not doing UI so I am use to reading and constructing nested structures.

This is not the best answer on how to use `format/2` to align code but it works.

```
everything_3 :-
    give_birth(X),
    give_eggs(Y),
    format('~s~t~14|~s~t~25|~s~t~25|~n', ['Animal Name: ',X,'Gives Birth']),
    format('~s~t~14|~s~t~25|~s~t~25|~n', ['Animal Name: ',Y,'Gives egg']),
    fail.
```

with

```
give_birth(cheetah).
give_birth(tiger).
give_birth(zebra).
give_eggs(ostrich).

?- everything_3.
Animal Name:  cheetah    Gives Birth
Animal Name:  ostrich    Gives egg
Animal Name:  tiger      Gives Birth
Animal Name:  ostrich    Gives egg
Animal Name:  zebra      Gives Birth
Animal Name:  ostrich    Gives egg
false.
```

> First to print all the animals that gives birth which are only 4(the rest are repeated in this output I don't know why). and then the rest of the animals that gives egg.

As I write this Paulo Moura just posted this part of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53433424/1243762) which is the same answer I was planing on giving, being to use a [failure-driven loop](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/pbrna/prologbook/node95.html) with a three clause predicate.

```
everything :-
    give_birth(X),
    format('Animal Name: \t~w,  \tGives Birth', X), nl,
    fail.
everything :-
    give_eggs(Y),
    format('Animal Name: \t~w,  \tGives egg', Y), nl,
    fail.
everything.
```

Here are the two answers combined with a sample run.

```
everything_4 :-
    give_birth(X),
    format('~s~t~14|~s~t~25|~s~t~25|~n', ['Animal Name: ',X,'Gives Birth']),
    fail.

everything_4 :-
    give_eggs(Y),
    format('~s~t~14|~s~t~25|~s~t~25|~n', ['Animal Name: ',Y,'Gives egg']),
    fail.

everything_4.

?- everything_4.
Animal Name:  cheetah    Gives Birth
Animal Name:  tiger      Gives Birth
Animal Name:  zebra      Gives Birth
Animal Name:  ostrich    Gives egg
true.
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the second problem, try:

```
everything :-
    give_birth(X),
    format('Animal Name: \t~w,  \tGives Birth', X), nl,
    fail.
everything :-
    give_eggs(Y),
    format('Animal Name: \t~w,  \tGives egg', Y), nl,
    fail.
everything.
```

This code will print first all animals that give birth, followed by all animals that give eggs. It uses the usually called *failure-driven loop*. The call to `fail/0` in the first clause results in backtracking to all solutions for the `give_birth /1` predicate. Similar for the second clause. The last clause simply makes the call to the `everything/0` predicate succeed after printing the information for all animals.